# Plot weekly hours with google charts

Tags: javascript, charts

Is it possibly in Goolge charts to plot the weekly hours of individuals where by the data would be split by days and hours within each day. I need to plot certain hours within the day that a person is in attendance.

The problem I've had so far is knowing *if* this is configurable via Google charts.

Or should I look at other charting tools like D3?